# When Laravel connects to the database (i.e mysql)?

Tags: laravel

Laravel only connects when the application is up? Or each query is a new connection?

I'm interested to know if the max_user connections is affected by each query or by each laravel instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It opens when you create a request, then closes it, just like php did for the request cycle. When a user comes and visits a page, it is handled by the nginx server then your app. If you store your request in your cache server, then there won't be any db call.